# Where'd my zpool data go?

Tags: zfs, zpool

N.B. I'm a complete noob when it comes to ZFS pools.

I created a ZFS pool yesterday across 4 3TB HDDs, like so:

```
2017-06-10.16:31:08 zpool create data sda sdc sdd sde
2017-06-10.16:31:29 zfs set compression=lz4 data
2017-06-10.16:31:43 zfs set atime=off data
```

Then I started copying some data in. Awhile later I notice that my pool is gone, and one of my harddrives is offline. I tried rebooting hoping that would bring it back online, but I get stuck in some kind of loop as described [here](https://blog.tastatursport.de/2016/05/zfs-mount-stuck-on-boot-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/). I didn't have time to deal with it yesterday, so I just shut the machine off until now.

I was about to try and recover from a USB stick, but I tried booting again, and the system came up fine! I run `zpool list` and it says "no pools available". Did some googling, tried `zpool import data`. I get an error,

> cannot mount '/data': directory is not empty

Tried `zpool list` again, and sure enough, we're back online:

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
data  10.9T   125G  10.8T         -     0%     1%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Tried `ls /data`, there's a directory in there, everything looks good. Check my [Minio](https://www.minio.io/) app which stores its data there, and all my buckets are gone. Sure enough, the only thing *actually* in `/data` is `/data/minio/.minio.sys` which the Minio service must have recreated when it came online. `zpool history` has this <del>scary</del> [scrubbing is OK] looking line in it:

```
2017-06-11.00:24:08 zpool scrub data
```

But I don't remember running that. The part I really don't get though, is that `zpool list` says that `125G` is still in use, which sounds about right. So,

1. Where *is* that data? How do I get access to it again?
2. I added `ZFS_MOUNT='no'` to `/etc/default/zfs` like that article suggests, but `systemctl enable zfs-mount.target` says "Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory" -- how am I *supposed* to automount my ZFS pool such that I won't get stuck during boot?
3. It appears I created my zpool incorrectly -- via their device names (e.g. `sda`) instead of UUIDs -- can I correct that now?

---

My USB stick is assigned a `/dev/sdX` letter isn't it? I suspect that has something to do with the mounting of the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You created a zpool comprised of a stripe of four disks; basically a RAID 0 of disks.
- You used SCSI /dev/sdX names and added a USB drive into the mix. This can cause SCSI enumeration issues and impact your /dev/sdX drive ordering.
- If you have something in the /data directory that shouldn't be there, just remove it and attempt to mount your pool - `zpool import data`

Comment: Aha!! It didn't even occur to me that `/data` could have been recreated on a different partition. I'm used to Windows where drive letters usually refer to a physical device. `zpool import data` said "cannot import 'data': a pool with that name already exists". I think `zfs mount` worked though, got my data back, thank you very much!

Comment: @mpen Drive letters on Windows typically refer to *partitions*, not physical devices.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's why I said "usually" :-) I know Windows can be partitioned, it's just less common to partition your drives. At least for me I don't bother. One dedicated drive for the OS, and another drive or 5 for data.

Comment: Will accept this. I never did figure out how to change from "sda" names to device-ids, but I think I needed to redo it to enable mirroring anyway. Seems to be mounting itself correctly now too.

Comment: @mpen Drive letters on Windows *never* refer to physical devices. Partitioning disks is normally *required* on Windows. You might typically make a single, large partition that covers the entire disk, which may optionally be referred to with a mount point, but in doing so you are absolutely partitioning the disk. If you want to explore the finer points of this further, I recommend asking a new question about it. I won't comment further on this answer on the subject of Windows storage.